# Zero locus and boundary of the subgraph of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Suppose one has a continuous function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$. Let $S=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $E:=f^{-1}((-\infty,0)).$ By the continuity of $f$, it is clear that $\partial E\subseteq S$, and there are easy example of continuous functions such that $S\subseteq \partial E$ does not hold: for $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R,x\mapsto|x|$ we have that $E=\varnothing$ so $\partial E=\varnothing,$ while $S=\{0\}.$ So, $S\subseteq \partial E$ isn't true.

My example is trivial, $\partial E$ is empty and $S$ is made by a single point.Are there more interesting example of continuous functions such that $S\subseteq \partial E$ doesn't hold?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = x^2(x - 1)$$

$S = \{0, 1\}$, but $\partial E = \{1\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking that there are a lot of examples like this, but we always have that the Lebesgue measure of $S$ and $\partial E$ is 0. Can we make example in which neither $S$ nor $\partial E$ have measure 0?

Comment: For $S$, easily. Just take the function above and move everything to the left of $0$ further left by $1$, defining $f(x) = 0$ on $(-1, 0)$. For $E$, I am not sure. Right now I cannot see how $\mu(\partial E) > 0$ is even possible, regardless of $S$. But I have not disproved it either, so maybe it is.